# Taking Backup of MySQL database using Java

Tags: java, mysql, backup

I need to take a backup of MySQL database using Java. i.e if I run the class file it should take the backup. i.e create dump file at particular location.

Comment: i have created connection to database and have tried to execute command to create backup using process

Comment: Sample code have been posted as a answer @prayag

Comment: don't do it. if you need backup, make it with proper tool. why do you need java for that? instead of "run the class', run e.g. `mysqldump` instead.

Comment: @prayag.. yes you can do it ....with java

Comment: can i ask why on earth you'd want to do this?

Comment: i am making the  program where it automatically takes the backup after certain time.so i need this class file to run automatically after some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User below code to take MySQL dump backup using Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File dir = new File("/root/");
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = runtime.exec("mysqldump database_name >/path-for-backpfile/database.sql", null, dir);


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = reader.readLine();


            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);

                line = reader.readLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException e1) {
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This my be sample solution for you.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/t";
    String user = "";
    String password = "";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM.........;");

        if (rs.next()) {//get first result
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));//coloumn 1
            //TODO Write on your file
        }
    //TODO 
//**Process your file **/

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Links: [Some example are here.](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=9)

To write on file: [How to write files in java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/)

Comment: This is not what i need. this is to execute any querry ..i need to take backup of complete database.